# Double/Triple Integral in R

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration, calculus

I am trying to solve below mentioned (image) equation in R for double integral over an area. I am using the following code by help of the following post:
[Triple integral in R (how to specifying the domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448144/triple-integral-in-r-how-to-specifying-the-domain)

Not sure, if I am missing anything as if I change value of A, it still gives me the same results. Is the following code correctly describing the equation I am trying to solve?

```
library(cubature)

PW <-  0.0144
Cw <- 400/(0.91*70)
A <- 1960                
w <- as.numeric(PW, Cw, A)

lower <- rep(0,3)
upper <- rep(1,3)

fxyz <- function(w) {
    x <- w[1]
    y <- w[2]
    z <- w[3]
    as.numeric(x <= y)*as.numeric(y <= z)
}

Int <- adaptIntegrate(f=fxyz,lowerLimit=lower,upperLimit=upper,doChecking=TRUE,
       maxEval=2000000,absError=10e-5,tol=1e-5)
```

thanks,
Krina

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `w` which is local to the definition of `fxyz` shadows the global `w` that you defined above. Changing `A` would have an effect on the global `w`, but that is quite irrelevant to the `w` which is local to `fxyz`. The reason that changing `A` has no effect on the value of the integral is that neither the integrand nor the limits of integration depend on `A`.

In response to your question: "Is the following code correctly describing the equation I am trying to solve?":  The code for the integral itself appears to be correct, but the code for `fxyz` apparently isn't. You seem to intend some dependence between that function and the parameters `Pw, Cw, A`, but you haven't explained what that dependence should be. Perhaps you could clarify, either here or in another question.

Comment: Thanks, John. The Pw is permeability, Cw is concentration, and A is surface area on intestine. I am trying to calculate double integration of (Pw*Cw) over domain A, which is surface area of intestine. Not sure what would be the exact dependence based on the above equation. I will try to dig more into theory of surface integrals. I am not very familiar with it.